# Unity + Mapbox IFeaturePropertySettable on Generated Mesh from Polygon?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox

I have been using the following example code with points and seems to work great but doesn't seem to work with polygons. I created a polygon building in mapbox studio gave it a property of prop_name and in Unity added a "AddMonobehaviourModifier" to it. The script gets added but the Set function is never ran when using a primitive type of Polygon. Only works with Point. Is this suppose to work with generated poly mesh or is there another way to get a property value from a polygon to use? I do have a height property that I made and setting the Property Name it is getting it from the Dataset. I just want all the other info from the properties of that Dataset to use as well.

```
namespace Mapbox.Examples
{
    using Mapbox.Unity.MeshGeneration.Interfaces;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;

    public class VisualizerElement : MonoBehaviour, IFeaturePropertySettable
    {
        public void Set(Dictionary<string, object> props)
        {
            if (props.ContainsKey("prop_name"))
            {       
                Debug.Log(props["prop_name"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up figuring this out. Use the **InteractiveStyledVectorMap** example. It was still a little complicated to setup and break apart. The first being I thought the **InspectorModifier** attached was a preset but it was actually a custom script to the example.. Mapbox is great but I feel like they need more documentation and better Unity SDK Descriptions.